# Optimizing writing equations for odeint

Tags: python, scipy, odeint

I wrote the following code for a simple chemical network to be solved by `odeint`:

```
def chemnet(y,t):
    assoc=0.1,0.001,1
    oxy=0.001,0.1,0.001
    f=zeros(6,float)
    f[0]= -2*assoc[0]*y[0]**2-assoc[1]*y[0]*y[1]-assoc[2]*y[0]*y[2]-oxy[0]*y[0]*y[4]+oxy[1]*y[1]*y[4]
    f[1]= +assoc[0]*y[0]**2-assoc[1]*y[0]*y[1]-oxy[1]*y[1]*y[4]+oxy[2]*y[2]*y[4]
    f[2]= +assoc[1]*y[0]*y[1]-assoc[2]*y[0]*y[2]-oxy[2]*y[2]*y[4]  
    f[3]= +assoc[2]*y[0]*y[2]
    f[4]= -oxy[0]*y[0]*y[4]-oxy[1]*y[1]*y[4]-oxy[2]*y[2]*y[4]
    f[5]= +oxy[0]*y[0]*y[4]+oxy[1]*y[1]*y[4]+oxy[2]*y[2]*y[4]
    return f
time = linspace(0.0,10.0,1000)
yinit = array([1,0,0,0,0.25,0]) 
y = odeint(chemnet,yinit,time)
```

As I'm expanding the size of the network, the number of equations and the length of each equation increases, as some species have many possible reactions. I would like to automate the process of creating these equations, i.e. in pseudocode:

```
#reaction 0+n->n+1
for n in range(len(assoc)):
    f[0].append(-assoc[n]*y[0]*y[n])
    f[n].append(-assoc[n]*y[0]*y[n])
    f[n+1].append(+assoc[n]*y[0]*y[n])
```

But I'm not quite sure how to do this, or if it's even possible. I'm still a bit of a python newbie, but it seems that this should be more straightforward than it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could automate the construction of the equation but it is much easier to automate the evaluation without explicitly constructing the equation.

Modifying your example:

```
def chemnet(y,t):
    assoc=0.1,0.001,1
    oxy=0.001,0.1,0.001
    f=zeros(6,float)
    f[0]= -oxy[0]*y[0]*y[4]+oxy[1]*y[1]*y[4]
    f[1]= -oxy[1]*y[1]*y[4]+oxy[2]*y[2]*y[4]
    f[2]= -oxy[2]*y[2]*y[4]  
    f[3]= 0.
    f[4]= -oxy[0]*y[0]*y[4]-oxy[1]*y[1]*y[4]-oxy[2]*y[2]*y[4]
    f[5]= +oxy[0]*y[0]*y[4]+oxy[1]*y[1]*y[4]+oxy[2]*y[2]*y[4]

    #reaction 0+n->n+1
    for n,assoc_n in enumerate(assoc):
        f[0] -= assoc_n*y[0]*y[n]
        f[n] -= assoc_n*y[0]*y[n]
        f[n+1] += assoc_n*y[0]*y[n]
    return f

time = linspace(0.0,10.0,1000)
yinit = array([1,0,0,0,0.25,0]) 
y = odeint(chemnet,yinit,time)
```

With linear relationships like this, you can also construct sparse interaction matrices and use matrix products to do your updates.